# Check input numbers in prolog

Tags: numbers, prolog

I would like to define a initial state in a problem.
My code is

```
isDigit(X) :-    ( number(X),
                   X >= 0,
                   X =< 8
                  ); ( writeln('[0-8] AND Number'),!,fail). 

define_initial_state(INITIAL_STATE) :- write('Pos (1,1):'),
                             read(A11),
                             isDigit(A11),
                             write('Pos (1,2):'),
                             read(A12),
                             isDigit(A12),
                             write('Pos (1,3):'),
                             read(A13),
                             isDigit(A13),
                             write('Pos (2,1):'),
                             read(A21),
                             isDigit(A21),
                             write('Pos (2,2):'),
                             read(A22),
                             isDigit(A22),
                             write('Pos (2,3):'),
                             read(A23),
                             isDigit(A23),
                             write('Pos (3,1):'),
                             read(A31),
                             isDigit(A31),
                             write('Pos (3,2):'),
                             read(A32),
                             isDigit(A32),
                             write('Pos (3,3):'),
                             read(A33),
                             isDigit(A33),
                             INITIAL_STATE = state(row1(A11,A12,A13), row2(A21,A22,A23),row3(A31,A32,A33)).



start :-  define_initial_state(INITIAL_STATE),
          write(INITIAL_STATE).
```

The problem I have is that is printed many times the message 
For example

```
1 ?- start.
Pos (1,1):4.
Pos (1,2):2.
Pos (1,3):11.
[0-8] AND Number
[0-8] AND Number
[0-8] AND Number
false.
```

Also I would like to check if a number is already given and if yes to ask again for this number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tried something for your `isDigit/1` predicate I'll help about that :

Version with an if structure :

```
isDigit(X) :-
    (   number(X),
        X >= 0,
        X =< 8
     -> true
     ;  writeln('[0-8] AND Number'),
        fail).
```

Version with a disjunction (as you tried in your OP) :

```
isDigit(X) :-
    number(X),
    X >= 0,
    X =< 8,
    !
    ;
    writeln('[0-8] AND Number'),
    fail.
```

The problem you had in your attempt was that you let a choice point when X was a number and meeting the right requirements, so the predicate would go there and print the error message and fail anyway. You used cut in the wrong part of the disjunction (correct version just above !).

Now, for the thing where you want to check if a number has already been given, please give it a try, edit your OP, and if you struggle somewhere we'll help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
It works but it is horrible

Also, I don;t know how can I ask user in case of input error 


to try another number.

isDigit(X) :-
    ( number(X),
     X >= 0,
     X =< 8
     -> true
     ;  writeln('[0-8] AND Number'),
    fail).

check_if_exists(Num,List) :- ( member(Num,List)
       -> true
                             ;
                             writeln('Num exist already')).        
                             
  
delete_one(Elem, [Elem|Tail], Tail).
delete_one(Elem, [Head|Tail1], [Head|Tail2]) :-
          \+ (Elem = Head),
 delete_one(Elem, Tail1, Tail2).

Comment: define_initial_state(INITIAL_STATE) :- L = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                                       write('Pos (1,1):'),
                  read(A11),
                  isDigit(A11),
            delete_one(A11,L,L1),
                  write('Pos (1,2):'),
                  read(A12),
                  isDigit(A12),       check_if_exists(A12,L1),
   delete_one(A12,L1,L2),
            ...
            INITIAL_STATE = state(row1(A11,A12,A13), row2(A21,A22,A23),row3(A31,A32,A33)).  
                  
          

      
start :-  define_initial_state(INITIAL_STATE),
      write(INITIAL_STATE).

Comment: edit your OP to post the code please, it's unreadable in comments... and what's horrible about my answer ?